# Display database table onto jQuery datatable (Liferay)

Tags: jquery, database, datatable, datatables, liferay

Following Liferay tutorial on setting up a guestbook and entry web portlet, i am currently able to display a table from the database using liferay container method to populate the result. [>>like this<<](https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-a-user-interface)

**This is a snippet of the container codes:**

```
<liferay-ui:search-container
    total="<%= GuestbookLocalServiceUtil.getGuestbooksCount(scopeGroupId) %>">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= GuestbookLocalServiceUtil.getGuestbooks(scopeGroupId, 
            searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.Guestbook" modelVar="guestbook">

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="name" />

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
            align="right" 
            path="/guestbookadminportlet/guestbook_actions.jsp" />

    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

**However, i am interested to display the result into a jQuery datatable and below is what i have done:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gbdb').DataTable();
} );
</script>

<%
List<Guestbook> guestbookList = GuestbookLocalServiceUtil.getGuestbooks(scopeGroupId);
request.setAttribute("guestbookList", guestbookList);
%>

  <table id="gbdb" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

  <c:forEach items="${guestbookList}" var="guestbook">
       <tr>
       <td>${guestbook.name}</td>
       <td> <link href="/guestbookadminportlet/guestbook_actions.jsp" /></td>
       </tr>
    </c:forEach>         
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Right now i am able to retrieve the entry from database but my question is how do i populate the guestbook_actions.jsp button on the second column? the original method just needs to set a path to the jsp page.** And also is there a better or preferably easier method of retrieving data from the database and display them in a datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Data tables are best with a combination of serve resource phase.

have a look here https://github.com/mir333/example/blob/master/SimpleShop/SimpleShopPortlet/src/main/java/eu/ibacz/example/simpleshop/portlet/catalog/CatalogPortlet.java

You can then just transfer a JSON that is then mapped in data tables according to this.
https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

the URL will be generated by

`<portlet:resourceURL var="queryURL" id="<%= RESOURCE_QUERY %>"/>`

Comment: i am quite at a loss on how to apply the serve and resource phase..and also understanding what the codes from the guthub does...

also how do i put the path inside resource_query?

Comment: basically, you are doing only an AJAX call to the server for JSON data. This is the same approach as you would do with any other technology (servlets, node....) The only difference instead of using a generic request to a URL you use the resource URL tag to generate you the resource URL to be used. This will be backed by the portal class and the serveResource method. have a look here http://www.opensource-techblog.com/2015/07/resource-url-by-liferay-portletresourceurl.html

Comment: You can serialise the data with any libt that you prefere Gson, jackson, or liferay has also a JSON serialiser.

Comment: Hmm so for my example the guestbook_actions.jsp which contains actions for the button has to be inside ResourceURLByLiferayTagPortlet.java? so i can call from view.jsp?

Comment: Yes if you want to include them in the JSON you need to generate them on the Java class side. You can generate them form the response object.

Comment: using the example of the link you provided to me, do you know what is the outcome? the outcome for me baiscally view has a link 'This is resource Url' and when i clicked on it, a pop out box appears saying 'null'..

Comment: is there any problem with my directory? seems the codes i used are 100% from the sites to test out. This is my directory: https://ibb.co/gHBNCT

Comment: HI i still have not solve this problem..
this is my view.jsp code from line 21 which display the datatables: https://pastebin.com/M5DPjizL

and my actions.jsp code which contains of a icon menu and its path to be referenced on the view.jsp page : https://pastebin.com/2mtPVrE1

Comment: I think you need to first take out the liferay out of the picture. Implement the table as if you would do just a simple web app and then provide the data over the ServerResource. Have a look on this https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html and this to achieve the actions https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/triggerButton.html. If you decided to use the DataTables don't mix the JSP code in any more.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to have a json objects for your database data

```
$sql = "select name,email from contact";

$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);

$json = array();
if($num > 0)
{
    while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($res))
    {
        $json[] = $obj;
    }
}
echo json_encode($json)
```

An alternative is [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crtwSmleWMA) for retrieving from database

afterwards you can use ajax to map them to a function